# Python: How do I convert the index (of list) to integer

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I need to take the average, minimum and maximum from this list, without using built in functions, but it throws an Exception:

```
File "<ipython-input-150-ff44c542ba16>", line 10, in problem2_8
    if temp_list[item]<lowest:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Here is my code:

```
hourly_temp = [40.0, 39.0, 37.0, 34.0, 33.0, 34.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, \
               40.0, 41.0, 44.0, 45.0, 47.0, 48.0, 45.0, 42.0, 39.0, 37.0, \
               36.0, 35.0, 33.0, 32.0]
def problem2_8(temp_list):
    total=0
    for item in temp_list:
        total=total+item
    print("Average: ",total/len(temp_list))
    low=0
    lowest= int(low)
    for item in temp_list:
        if temp_list[item]<lowest:
            lowest=temp_list[list]
    print("Low: ",lowest)
```

Comment: So what do you think is the problem? The error message seems pretty clear. You need to use the ordinal index values to index into a list not the values themselves

Comment: Do a ``for index, item in enumerate(temp_list)``. And then use ``index`` not an ``item``.

Comment: That's not how the "for each" loop works. Perhaps you should go back to the [`for` loop tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and read more about it? As a hint of what's going on, try *printing* `item` in the loop.

Comment: I tried and it worked fine, can you please explain how did it worked ?
I'm a newbie to python

Comment: @ChiliMili Please read the tutorial as suggested above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply iterate in the second loop too:

```
hourly_temp = [40.0, 39.0, 37.0, 34.0, 33.0, 34.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, \
               40.0, 41.0, 44.0, 45.0, 47.0, 48.0, 45.0, 42.0, 39.0, 37.0, \
               36.0, 35.0, 33.0, 32.0]

def problem2_8(temp_list):
    total=0
    for item in temp_list:
        total = total + item
    print("Average: ", total / len(temp_list))
    lowest=float('inf')  # the temporary lowest should be really big (not small)
    for item in temp_list:
        if item < lowest:
            lowest = item
    print("Low: ", lowest)

problem2_8(hourly_temp)
```

But in case you're interested using the built-in functions `sum` and `min` could make this much easier:

```
def problem2_8(temp_list):
    print('Average', sum(temp_list) / len(temp_list))
    print('Lowest', min(temp_list))
```

In case you have python >= 3.4 you could also use [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) instead of dividing the sum by the length:

```
from statistics import mean

def problem2_8(temp_list):
    print('Average', mean(temp_list))
    print('Lowest', min(temp_list))
```

Comment: I think that his assignment requiere him not too use them, so that he know how to do it, nice explanation still

Comment: Yes, I read that they aren't allowed - but I thought the answer would be incomplete without at least showing how it "could be done". :)

Comment: I've the following code now working very fine on my data, but the coursera autograde fails it, any idea how ?
`def problem2_8(temp_list):
    total=0
    for item in temp_list:
        total=total+item
    print("Average: ",total/len(temp_list))
    
    highest= hourly_temp[0]
    for item in temp_list:
        if item>highest:
            highest=item
    print("Highest: ",highest)
    
    lowest= hourly_temp[0]
    for item in temp_list:
        if item<lowest:
            lowest=item
    print("Low: ",lowest)`

Comment: Without indentation it's hard to make sure if it's correct. But at a quick glance it seems correct. Maybe you're not formatting it correctly. Currently there will be two whitespaces after `Lowest:`, etc. Maybe try it with `print('Lowest: {}'.format(lowest))` and similarly for the others.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easy to solve. The code can be changed thus.

```
hourly_temp = [40.0, 39.0, 37.0, 34.0, 33.0, 34.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, \
               40.0, 41.0, 44.0, 45.0, 47.0, 48.0, 45.0, 42.0, 39.0, 37.0, \
               36.0, 35.0, 33.0, 32.0]

def problem2_8(temp_list):
    total=0
    for item in temp_list:
        total=total+item
    print("Average: ",total/len(temp_list))
    lowest= temp_list[0] # Point a
    for item in temp_list: # Point b
        if item<lowest: # Point c
            lowest=item # Point d
    print("Low: ",lowest)

 problem2_8 (hourly_temp)
```

So here is the explanation of how it works

Point a: I am not sure why you had defined a low, which would be an integer, and then said lowest was the int of low. I have no idea why that exists. What you actually want is to set it to the first value arbitrarily, which is what I have done.

Point b: Each item is the item in the list. It is not the integer of each item, it gives you the value of each item

Point c: As you have the value of the item, you should directly compare it to lowest

Point d: You should then set the lowest value as the new one

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the floating point numbers as indices. So try this

```
for i in range(len(temp_list)): 
     if temp_list[i]<lowest:                  
              lowest=temp_list[i]
 print("Low: ",lowest)
```

If you do not want to use the len() as well. Try this

```
for item in temp_list: 
         if item<lowest:                  
                  lowest=item
     print("Low: ",lowest)
```

And finally your question you could convert float to int by typecasting it. `int(item)` is one way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in temp_list:
```

Return the element  and not the index, you then just use for your conditions:

```
if item <lowest:
```

If you want to use the index, you can use :

```
for item in range(len(temp_list)):
```

or even using enumeration :

```
for index,value in enumerate(temp_list):
```

Also, next time you may want to print the value that made the error to see if it is what you expected